# ML project ideas for dataset

Tags: data-mining, dataset, text

Not sure if this is the right forum, but currently i have a dataset which contains a list of TV shows. Each record contains pricing between competitors (price in provider 1. Example: Itunes) TV show cover image, synopsis, country of origin, language, etc. Looking for ideas what project is suggested that i can prototype it, i want to learn ML and this may be a useful dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first ML project, you should try to predict one feature with the other features; i.e., see if highest bidder can be predicted based on cover image, synopsis, country of origin, etc. For this you can use a basic NN as a baseline, and keep adding layers until it's powerful enough. To choose the feature to be predicted, you can make a correlation matrix or use random forests to make sure there are some relationships within the data and you're not simply trying to predict an uncorrelated variable.

A little bit more difficult would be to predict the precise pricing a provider would give a movie based on the price it's given other movies (of course, without looking at the other competitors' pricing).

The hardest, I think, would be to use the cover image as input to a CNN in order to predict the genre of movie, country of origin, etc.